How to create root domain alias in Windows DNS Server?
I have an old domain, say exist.com and I've registered newone.xyz and I don't want to create a primary zone for the newer one.
Can I redirect any queries for newone.xyz to exist.com and how can I do that if it's possible?

In windows DNS you can create a conditional forwarder to forward the requests from one domain to another. https://www.readandexecute.com/how-to/server-2016/dns/configure-conditional-forwarders-windows-server-2016/
